# even after running migrations Django Programming error column does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, nginx

At first on my project everthing is works fine but after I added field to model everything is broken.I am working on ubuntu with postgresql.(Django project) .I deleted migrations folder and django_migrations folder but nothing is change.Everytime I get this error.Can anyone please help me??

[image]

Comment: Show us code of yours view which is at / route

Answer (score 0):

After a change in the model you need to create new migrations with `manage.py makemigrations` and apply them using `manage.py migrate`.

Usually old migrations are not deleted and committed to VCS. If you deleted the old migrations start with a fresh database.

More information regarding see [Migrations in the Django-Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/). Also have a look at the generated migrations when you change your models.

Comment: I tried but nothing change.I can't delete my postgresql db because every information in that

Comment: If your production database is out of sync with the migrations all i can think of is run the migrations locally in a fresh database and create the fields manually in the production database.

Comment: Also have a look at the `django_migrations` table in the database. I has information on the migrations that have already been run. If new ones have the same name they will count as applied.